# Angular 2 binding expression in string (ng2-translate)

Tags: angularjs, json, angular, localization

I am working on internationalization in angular 2 using ng2-translate. 
I have a label which contains string as follows:

```
<label> Step {{stepNumber}} of {{totalSteps}} </label>
```

where stepNumber and totalSteps are properties in my component.

for internationalization I am storing a key in my resource files and utilizing with ng2-translate pipe.

en.json:

```
{
  "KEY_STEP_COUNT": "Step {{stepNumber}} of {{totalSteps}}"
}
```

fr.json:

```
{
  "KEY_STEP_COUNT": "Étape {{stepNumber}} sur {{totalSteps}}"
}
```

an utilizing it in my html as follows:

```
<label> {{ 'KEY_STEP_COUNT' | translate}} </label>
```

The output I get is

en:

```
"Step {{stepNumber}} of {{totalSteps}}"
```

fr:

```
"Étape {{stepNumber}} sur {{totalSteps}}"
```

Expected Output:

en:

```
"Step 1 of 11"
```

fr:

```
"Étape 1 sur 11"
```

Is is possible to add an expression in a string binding with angular2?

I want to use angular2 bindings and not string.replace if it is possible.

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: Hi shaikhspear, can you share the basics of how you configured ng2-translate for angular2.. I got so far with my last attempt but in the end there was a problem with the global-wide registration of the translate pipe in the module using transle-module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add an object as a pipe parameter like :

`{{ 'KEY_STEP_COUNT' | translate: {stepNumber: 15, totalSteps: 25} }}`

Comment: Great!!! Thank You. further to add to this, we can use TranslateParser in type script. `this.parser.interpolate(this.translateService.instant("KEY_STEP_COUNT"), { maxUploadSize: maxUploadSize }));`