# How can I get a template binding expression as string in Angular2?

Tags: angular, ngmodel, binding-expressions

Is there any way to get the string "myModel" in my component?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myModel"/>`
})
export class AppComponent { // how can I access "myModel" here? }
```

Comment: This would be pretty basic... maybe check out tutorials?? ;) https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html

Comment: I don't mean the value of myModel but the string literal "myModel".

Answer (score 0):

Simply access it with

```
this.myModel
```

and declare it before.

```
myModel:string;
```

Comment: No sorry, I don't mean the value of myModel but the string literal "myModel".

Comment: I don't understand your use-case? ngModel binds the value of the input to the given variable in your case myModel. Please clearify your question. It seems like you don't understand what the binding is for... Do you wan't to pass a value to your component?

Comment: use case would be simple. assuming we have an address component and the main component does bind to: model.HomeAddress and model.PostalAddress (via property or ngModel - depends on implementation), then i'd like to know the binding expression, so i'd like to get either "model.HomeAddress" or the "model.PostalAddress" string. if you don't get why, don't ask, if you don't know how to do, don't answer. simply there's a reasonable UC (based on composition) where this might be needed.

Comment: just like it's possible to translate/evaluate an expression: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39765063/angular-2-binding-expression-in-string-ng2-translate it also makes sense to grab that expression :D

Comment: Okay, I must admit you stated that in your question, but to me it was a bit obscure, regarding to the use cases I could think of, but that doesn't matter. If you still need a possible solution the ViewChild-Decorator may help https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild . I couldn't test it because it is a bit late.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest i could come to NgModel was in the ctor via injector.view - but need to do some changes based on http://blog.rangle.io/angular-2-ngmodel-and-custom-form-components/ to see if i'll be able to get those expressions. should anyone get an answer sooner than me, please, post it here. thanx.

Comment: tried also the component with ngModel binding (see url above), yet no luck to grab that expression